# Ml inequality for $\log(z+i)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

I do not need a complete proof, just a hint. This is what the problem is:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2} dx$$

Over this contour:

[image: Contour, with radius R]

The radius is $R$ from the midpoint.

I am trying to prove somehow:

$$\oint_{A} f(z) dz = 0$$

Using the Ml inequality - [Estimation Lemma, ML-inequality.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estimation_lemma)

First we take the first part of the expression:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log(z+i)}{1 + z^2}$$

The obvious beginning is to parametrize,

$$z = Re^{i\theta}$$

$$\log(Re^{i\theta} + i) < M_1$$

I am first trying to find an upper-bound for $\log(z+i)$

We know:

$$\log(z) = \log|z| + iarg(z)$$

So then, obviously,

$$\log(Re^{i\theta} + i) = \log(|Re^{i\theta}) + i|) + i\theta$$

$$= \log(\sqrt{(Re^{i\theta})^2 - 1}) + i\theta$$

The value of $1$ reduces the logarithm so therefore, And $\theta \le \pi$ so:

$$= \log(\sqrt{(Re^{i\theta})^2 - 1}) + i\theta < \log(R) + 2i\pi \le |\log(R) + 2i\pi| = \sqrt{\log^2(R) - 4\pi^2} \le M_1$$

$$|z^2 + 1| > R^2 - 1$$

$$\therefore, \frac{1}{|z^2 + 1|} < \frac{1}{R^2 - 1}$$

$$M \ge \frac{\sqrt{\log^2(R) - 4\pi^2}}{R^2 - 1}$$

Where $M$ denotes $\max|f(z)|$

$L(A)$ is the arclengthof the contour $A$ simply equal to:

$$L(A) = (1/2)(2)(\pi)(R) = \pi R$$

Hence:

$$\left| \oint_{A} f(z) dz  \right | \le ML(A)= \frac{(\pi R)\cdot\sqrt{\log^2(R) - 4\pi^2}}{R^2 - 1}$$

$$\lim_{R \to \infty} \frac{(\pi R)\cdot\sqrt{\log^2(R) - 4\pi^2}}{R^2 - 1} = 0$$

But I am not sure if the $ML$ inequality even applies, because I dont if how to find $\max|f(z)|$

Can someone justify if this work is valid,

Or how to actually use the ML Inequality? Please?

Thanks!

Comment: It's $|f(z)| = \Bigg|\frac{\log (1 + z^2)}{1+z^2}\Bigg| = \frac{|\log (1 + z^2)|}{|1+z^2|}$. So you estimate $|\log (1+z^2)|$ and $|z^2+1|$ to find the maximum value of $f(z)$.

Answer (score 1):

Over $A$, $x=Re^{i\theta}$ with $\theta\in[0,\pi]$. Since:
$$ \log(1+x^2) = 2\log(x) + \log\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right),$$
assuming $R\geq e^{\pi}$, for any $x\in A$ we have:
$$ \left|\log(1+x^2)\right| \leq 4 \log R, $$
so: $$\left|\oint_{A}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx\right|\leq \frac{4\pi R}{R^2-1}\log R \to 0.$$

---

By the way, there is a clever real analytic technique for evaluating:
$$ I = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\log(1+x^2)}{1+x^2}\,dx=\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\log(1+\tan^2\theta)\,d\theta = -\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin t\,dt $$
that is to exploit the identity:
$$ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\sin\frac{\pi k}{n}=\frac{2n}{2^n}.$$
Since, considering Riemann sums:
$$\int_{0}^{\pi}\log\sin t\,dt = \lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{\pi}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\log\sin\frac{\pi k}{n},$$
we just have:
$$ I = \color{red}{\pi\log 2}.$$

Comment: This is a good method, but there has to be a problem. If this is correct, my method has to be incorrect, or can there be multiply correct answers? +1

Comment: @Amad27: if two roads lead to the same place ($\oint_A\to 0$, for instance), there is not necessarily a right and a wrong path, but only one longer and one shorter.

Comment: Thank you Jack D' Aurizio, you are amazing. Mine led to that expression, but I am not sure if this was valid:

$$\left | \oint_{A} f  \right | \le \frac{(\pi R)\cdot\sqrt{\log^2(R) - 4\pi^2}}{R^2 - 1}$$

Because I compared the absolute values. Is my approach correct actually?

Comment: @Amad27: yes, the key argument is just to bound the absolute value of the integral with something like $C\frac{\log R}{R}$ that tends to zero as $R\to +\infty$.

Comment: Thats the issue, I dont have $\log(R)/R \cdot C$ like you do, which why I am worried I didnt apply this properly.

Comment: @Amad27: what you have is, asymptotically, $\pi\frac{\log R}{R}$. The constants $-4\pi^2$ and $-1$ do not play a major role: you can prove, for instance, that your bound is $\leq 2\pi\frac{\log R}{R}$ for any $R$ big enough.

Comment: Okay, that is good. It wasnt that long (on paper) either. So I suppose this is right. By the way, a question. For the actual integral, we cant apply the residue theorem, there are no poles, so is there a way to tackle this integral as one piece?

Comment: @Amad27: in $x=i$ there is a singularity for sure.

Comment: Thats weird, WolframAlpha returns no residues

Comment: Oh no, I see why, log does exist there. By the way I have done this problem before with real methods too. I used the beta function (improper version) and differentiated and used digamma to get this answer.